# MaterialApp's theme primary color doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart

On this flutter sample secondary color works fine but primary color doesn't seem to work why is that?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = ThemeData();
   
    return MaterialApp(
      
      theme: theme.copyWith(
        colorScheme: theme.colorScheme.copyWith(
          primary: Colors.blue,
          secondary: Colors.orange,
        )
      ),
      
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`theme: ThemeData( primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800], accentColor: Colors.yellow, ),`

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = ThemeData();
   
    return MaterialApp(
      
     theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ).copyWith(
      secondary: Colors.green,
    ),
      
      home: MyHomePage(),
    ));
  }
}
```